# How to clean up after a failed windows 10 update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

I started updating my windows 10 and it failed with:

[image: Some update files are missing or have problems.]

I tried updating it again and this time I got:

> Updates are available, but we temporarily need some space to install. Let's clear some space by removing any files and apps that you don't need and we'll try again.

And I noticed that the previously failed update + the second try has been taking space. I freed up around 2GB more space and my next try failed again saying you don't have enough space while taking more space.

Simply each time I start updating it starts from 0% goes to 100% takes up my newly freed up space, fails with you don't have enough space.

Now I ended up with a failed update and nothing more to free up and I don't have the space that I had before I begun updating.

- WIN10 build 1903
- Drive C: 19GB
- Nothing more to remove or add.

How can I resolve the problem, and at least get the space I had before starting the update.

Comment: If you installed Windows 10 on a 19 GB partition then you installed Windows on a partition that isn’t large enough.

Comment: Thanks and Yeah, I know that and I didn't intend to update it at all, the only problem here is how to get back my 4GB of free space, my hard disk is a combination of Luks and LVM so it's not really easy for me to add more free space.

Comment: Your going to have to disable Windows Update before you do anything otherwise it will continue to check for updates and fill up your space.  If this is a new install, time to increase the partition size, and prevent this issue from happening all together

Comment: See if it left behind Windows.old before it failed. Run Admin Tools, Disk Cleanup, and select Clean up System Files. Make sure all categories have been selected. Say OK to request to clean up old Windows Updates.  Allow to complete, restart and then see if you have 25 - 30 GB of free space to be able to update.

Comment: Did you try using Windows disk cleanup to cleanup windows update files?

Comment: Thank you all, Disk cleanup did nothing, I ended up re-partitioning and extending Drive C to complete the update but still filling my hard drive after each failing at updates is a  mystery to me... I'm a GNU/Linux user so yeah I can't get it in no way.